# Git deployment strategy for a distributed web application

Tags: git, security, deployment, ssh-keys, ansible

I have a PHP web application running the same code on two servers (more maybe added) behind a load balancer.
The code are kept in a private BitBucket repository. I am having trouble figuring out an optimal deployment strategy for the situation.

Currently, I am already using Ansible to provision the servers, so what I did is to use the [Git module](http://docs.ansible.com/git_module.html) to checkout the code from the repository into the server. Since the code are stored in a private repository, I added a play to copy an authorized ssh private key to the servers, which will later be specified as the key file during git checkout. The key is encrypted with the [Ansible Vault](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_vault.html).

The keys and the provisioning playbook are checked into git as well.

It is working out pretty well so far, but although I am not sure what's wrong with it, I am concerned about the security. I can't help but feel that I did something wrong by checking the ssh key into VCS, and also by using the same key across all servers.

What should've I done to keep it secure?

Answer (score 0):

This question is very broad, but I'd say using Ansible Vault is the right approach.  You are checking in your ssh keys in a git repository but they are encrypted and you can only decrypt them with your password.

If you want to improve even more security you can try creating `4096` or `8192` ssh keys like I do. In general ssh key authentication is pretty secure because there's unique fingerprint generated every time you use your private/public key pair.

Answer (score 0):

Thats pretty much a big subject and what might be secure for me might not be for you.

But generally its okay but I would keep the following points.

- Use that deploys should have limited access on what he can do (if possible)
- You can use the authorized_keys to limit the source of key if it was compromised http://man.he.net/man5/authorized_keys
- As said by Rico use higher bits key